# How to insert an array using sails waterline into a postgresql table?

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I want to insert an array of strings in one column of a postgresql table using waterline **ORM** of `sailsjs`.

I have tried making the model `Users.js` like this :

```
 interest:{
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
      columnType: 'array'
    }
```

The insert query goes like this:

```
Users.create({ interest : ['programming'] });
```

The datatype in postgre table for interest column is `character varying[]`.

When i try to perform an insert using this setup, it throws an error:

```
 Specified value (a array: [ 'programming' ]) doesn't match the expected type: 'string'
```

how can I insert an array in the postgresql table, how should the model look like?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use curly braces when inserting an array into a postgres db. So have you tried stringifying the array before creating it. For example, `Users.create({interest : JSON.stringify(['programming'])})`

Comment: @Glen It gives an error `malformed array literal`

Comment: How about `Users.create({interest : JSON.stringify(['programming']).replace(/\[/g, '{').replace(/]/g, '}')})`. Very ugly though :)

Comment: @Glen Thanks, It works fine.But I think there could be a more proper way of doing that.

Comment: Had a quick look into the code, can you try changing the attribute type to json, `interest: {
      type: 'json',
      required: false,
      columnType: 'array'
}` and just pass like `Users.create({ interest : ['programming'] });`

Comment: @Glen It produces the same error `malformed array literal: "["programming"]"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191503/discussion-between-rajan-sharma-and-glen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use PG arrays quite a bit throughout my projects and have never had any issues using `type: 'ref'` then specifying a postgres array type in `columnType`. Something like the following:

```js
 things: {
  type: 'ref',
  columnType: 'text[]',
  defaultsTo: null, // or defaultsTo: []
  description: 'An array of stringy-things',
},
```

PG array type docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html, but basically you want probably want to use `<TYPE>[]` for your columnTypes, ie `integer[]`, etc